# Android app published to Play Store then add Firebase notifications crash

Tags: android, firebase, notifications, firebase-notifications

I have an Android app published in Play Store then I added Firebase notifications.

When a user updates the app from Google Play, the app crashes and doesn't open.

Does this problem from google-services.json file? or from other thing?

Comment: **note: the old version of app not have firebase notification

Comment: What the error message?

Comment: no error message but app crashed and not opened

Comment: Try to reproduce the same in debug mode. If you have not used Proguard, install the app on your device, connect it to Android Studio, open your app & check the logs as soon as it crashes. Tip : Use Firebase crashlytics - https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics